# How do I add a column to a temp table inside a stored procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server, procedure, temp

I have a stored procedure similar to below:

```
ALTER Proc   
BEGIN    
    if object()... drop... #temp_table

    select 
        a,
        b,
    INTO #temp_table
    From physical_table    

    if object()... drop... physical_table2

    select *
    into physical_table2
    From #temp_table    
END
```

I want to add an additional column inside the temp table in the stored procedure

LIKE:

```
ALTER Proc    
BEGIN    
    select 
        a,
        b,
        C <-- NEW COLUMN ADDED
    INTO #temp_table
    From physical_table

    select *
    into physical_table2
    From #temp_table
END
```

However, I'm getting the "invalid column name 'C' error

Now, this is an easy fix... I could just highlight and run the inside statement of the stored procedure first and then execute the "Alter Proc" statement, BUT I need to give the script to IT to execute it. I was told to create another script before the stored proc script to alter the temp table and add that column... but unsure how to do that??

Answer (score 0):

This code:

```
select a, b, C <-- NEW COLUMN ADDED
INTO #temp_table
From physical_table
```

Assumes that `C` is in physical table.  The error suggests that it is not.  You can assign a constant value:

```
select a, b, 0 as C <-- NEW COLUMN ADDED
INTO #temp_table
From physical_table;
```

Comment: the column needed to be added is there